# How to detect fullscreen api support with pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

This is the API I'm referring to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

As for what I've tried so far:

Modernizr has the `Modernizr.fullscreen` thing, but I don't feel like using yet another library for what seems like a simple task.

So I'm digging the source code of Modernizr to try and see how they do it, after all Modernizr does use JS to figure it out, right? But so far all I found about the fullscreen API in their source code is this file (Modernizr/feature-detects/fullscreen-api.js)

```
/*!
{
  "name": "Fullscreen API",
  "property": "fullscreen",
  "caniuse": "fullscreen",
  "notes": [{
    "name": "MDN Docs",
    "href": "https://developer.mozilla.org/en/API/Fullscreen"
  }],
  "polyfills": ["screenfulljs"],
  "builderAliases": ["fullscreen_api"]
}
!*/
/* DOC
Detects support for the ability to make the current website take over the user's entire screen
*/
define(['Modernizr', 'prefixed'], function(Modernizr, prefixed) {
  // github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/739
  Modernizr.addTest('fullscreen', !!(prefixed('exitFullscreen', document, false) || prefixed('cancelFullScreen', document, false)));
});
```

...and I don't quite understand that code. yet.

Comment: Have you tried `Document.fullscreenEnabled` as documented [here?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API#Properties)

Comment: `if (document.documentElement.requestFullscreen){...}`

Comment: To clarify: You want to detect whether the user has the page full screen? Or you want to force the page to be full screen?

Comment: @tomcek112 no but I will, thanks!

Comment: @Calvin Nunes Thanks, 'will try that too.

Comment: @Polyducks I want to detect if the browser CAN go fullscreen; for instance safari on iOS will never allow a website to make a div fullscreen (not even a video)

Comment: @FelDev please update us with what worked for you so we can post an answer and accept it

Comment: @tomcek112 yes of course, so far document.fullscreenEnabled is out because it gives undefined on desktop Safari

Comment: You'll want to check in the Modernizr sources what `addTest` and `prefixed` do. Probably it detects whether the current engine is using prefixed properties (instead of the standard ones), then simply checks whether the property exists in `document`.

Comment: Can you try something like `const fullScreenAvailable = document.fullscreenEnabled || document.mozFullscreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled ? true : false`

Comment: @tomcek112 Yeah, the final solution is most probably going to be something along those lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following snippet seems to be the best solution:

```
const fullScreenAvailable = document.fullscreenEnabled || 
                            document.mozFullscreenEnabled ||
                            document.webkitFullscreenEnabled ||
                            document.msFullscreenEnabled
```

Comment: and w3schools agrees!
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_fullscreenenabled.asp